# How to append this in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to add a new line in this. This is my sample code:

```
ui->button->setText(" Tips " + "\n" + TipsCount );
```

This is the error it shows:

> invalid operands of types 'const char [7]' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'

But when I add to label it gets appended!

```
 ui->label->setText(name + "\n" + City );
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common problem in C++ (in general, not just QT).

Thanks to the magic of operator overloading, `name + "\n"` gets turned into a method call (couldn't say which one since you don't list the type). In other words, because one of the two things is an object with `+` overloaded it works.

However when you try to do `"abc" + "de"`, it blows up. The reason is because the compiler attempts to add two arrays together. It doesn't understand that you mean concatenation,  and tries to treat it as an arithmetic operation.

To correct this, wrap your string literals in the appropriate string object type (`std::string` or `QString` most likely).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bart!!! It works Fine!!!:)                                                                     ui->button->setText(QString(" Tips ") + "\n"  +  TipsCount );

Comment: @Naufal I have removed my answer. This one does a much better job at explaining the "why". If this answers your question (which I assume it does) then you might accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Bart, I am getting the text at the center in the pushbutton., can i align it to bottam of the push button.. is there any property or code to be addded???

Comment: That should be a different (new) question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little case study:

```
QString h = "Hello";               // works
QString w = "World";               // works too, of course

QString a = h + "World";           // works
QString b = "Hello" + w;           // also works

QString c = "Hello" + "World";     // does not work
```

*String literals* in C++ (text in quotes) are not objects and don't have methods...just like numeric values aren't objects.  To make a string start acting "object-like" it has to get wrapped up into an object.  `QString` is one of those wrapping objects, as is the `std::string` in C++.

Yet the behavior you see in **a** and **b** show we're somehow able to *add a string literal to an object*.  That comes from the fact that Qt has defined global operator overloads for both the case where the left operand is a QString with the right a `const char*`:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#operator-2b-24

...as well as the other case where the left is a `const char*` and the right is a QString:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#operator-2b-27

If those did not exist then you would have had to write:

```
QString a = h + QString("World");
QString b = QString("Hello") + w;
```

You could still do that if you want.  In that case what you'll cause to run will be the addition overload for both operands as QString:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#operator-2b-24

But if even *that* didn't exist, you'd have to call a member function.  For instance, append():

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#append

In fact, you might notice that there's no overload for appending an integer to a string.  (There's one for a `char`, however.)  So if your `TipsCount` is an integer, you'll have to find some way of turning it into a QString.  The static `number()` methods are one way.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#number

So you might find you need:

```
ui->button->setText(QString(" Tips ") + "\n" + QString::number(TipsCount));
```